# ASP.NET Core can’t assign span name to local variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-validators

I add dynamic inputs to my form and when I add I dynamically create a name for my input and set it. But, I can't set the same value to the span asp-validation-for parameter. My code:

```
@model AnswerViewModel


<fieldset class="row answerrow" style="margin: 20px;" id="@Model.answer.Id">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.answer.Id" name="@Model.NameofAnswerIdInput" value="@Model.answer.Id" ></input>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.answer.QuestionId" name="@Model.NameofQuestionIdInput" value="@Model.answer.QuestionId" />


        <div id="@Model.answer.Id" class="d-flex form-group">
            <input required="true" asp-for="@Model.CorrectAnswerId" name="@Model.NameofCorrectAnswerIdRadio" 
                   type="radio" value="@Model.answer.Id" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.NameofCorrectAnswerIdRadio" class="text-danger"></span>
            
            <input id="@Model.answer.Id" required="true" asp-for="@Model.answer.Content" 
                   name="@Model.NameofContentInput" value="@Model.answer.Content" class="form-control ms-2" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.NameofContentInput" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I check through inspect, the span name is set as "data-valmsg-for="NameofContentInput". How can I set the span name correctly to the "@Model.NameofContentInput"?

Comment: The browser will output source of HTML...  ASP.NET will read/interpret the @... directives... so after processing @Model.NameOfContentInput.... that output will be the value of NameOfContentInput in your view model (.cs file defines the model.. which should be "AnswerViewModel"?).

Comment: But the '@' directive does not interpret and the result occurs like that: <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="NameofContentInput" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>. Instead of assigning the value of @Model.NameofContentInput to the data-valmsg-for,  it results with data-valmsg-for="NameofContentInput"

Answer (score 1):

The asp-validation-for tag helper is used for the model's property not for the mode's property's name. This is the reason why `asp-validation-for="@Model.NameofContentInput"` will render as `data-valmsg-for="NameofContentInput"` not the `data-valmsg-for="test"`.

More details you could refer to the [ValidationMessageTagHelper's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs) source coeds.

It will use [this method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/87144203fb2471183a5ed240a8ceb3f4836dfab0/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L710) to generate the html, you could find it will generate the html basked on the property name not the value.